# Сверстать две колонки с неизвестными ширинами, одна сжимается по контенту, в другой скроллбар

Tags: css, вёрстка

Всем привет.
Застрял на версточной задаче:

https://jsfiddle.net/zhp27z5t/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__primary">

        <div class="scrollable">
            <div class="scrollable__inner"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container__secondary">

        <div class="strut">I&nbsp;am&nbsp;short</div>

    </div>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
}
    .container__primary {
        width: 500px;
    }

    .container__secondary {
        width: 100px;
    }

.scrollable {
    overflow-x: auto;
}    
    .scrollable__inner {
        width: 4000px;
        height: 50px;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
    }

.strut {
    line-height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}
```

С проставленными ширинами все работает. Но ширины колонок проставлены для примера. Нужно сделать без ширин.

- Контейнер должен занимать 100% выделенной ему ширины родителями (в
  примере это просто весь body).
- Правая колонна должна схлопываться по ширине контента.
- Левая должна быть жадной и занимать все оставшееся пространство.
  Причем в глубине левой колонны будет использоваться блок с
  горизонтальным скроллбаром.

Простые методы типа инлайн-блоков, обтекания, абсолютного позиционирования не подходят, так как неизвестны ширины. Таблички тоже не подходят, так внутри не будет работать скроллбар (длинный блок просто разуплотнит табличку). Пробую флексы, но тут либо таже самая проблема, что и с таблицами, либо левая колонна занимает 100% ширины выталкивая правую за границу контейнера.

У меня есть надежда на то, что я чего-то еще не знаю про флексы или чего-то в них не понимаю. Прошу помощи. Спасибо :)

Comment: я запутался, какие ширины должны остаться и какие убраться?

Comment: Ширин не должно быть вообще. Для примера я их поставил левой и правой колоннам. Иначе просто структура была бы непонятна при открытии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ух, ну и задачка. Разрулить можно с помощью [`flex-shrink`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-shrink):

```css
/* Косметика */
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
/* Сам код */
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container__primary {
  flex: 1 100;
  min-width: 0; /* Чтобы сжималось в Firefox и Chrome */
}
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.scrollable__inner {
  width: 4000px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
}
.strut {
  line-height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__primary">

    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="scrollable__inner"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container__secondary">

    <div class="strut">I&nbsp;am&nbsp;short</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Я использую здесь shorthand [`flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex) и заведомо большое значение для `flex-shrink` — 100.

`min-width: 0;` — позволяет сжиматься блоку меньше своего изначального размера в Firefox и Chrome. Без этого хака код работает только в Edge, IE и Yandex Browser.

---

**Проверено (с хаком) работает** в IE, Yandex Browser, Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi

---

Использована подсказка из ответа на вопрос [Firefox Not Respecting Flex Shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790219/firefox-not-respecting-flex-shrink)

Comment: мне кажется скролл должен был быть внутри первой колонки, а не у боди.

Comment: @Grundy У боди нет скролла... О чем вы?

Comment: По крайней мере в хроме первая колонка растягивается по контенту. Проверил в IE - все нормально. В FF - тоже не работает

Comment: @Grundy, я дополнил ответ, относительно ограниченной работы в браузерах. Странно, но в Yandex Browser работает как надо.

Comment: а вот это интересно, учитывая что база с хромом одна

Comment: что интересно - после фикса для FF - в хроме тоже заработало:)

Comment: @Grundy, я не успел проверить просто :)

Comment: Ребята, это работает. Проверил еще в Edge - все четенько. Спасибо!